# how to set page number in angular2-datatable

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I am using `angular2-datatable` to display data. Source : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable

I want to know if is there any way to set particular page number in pagination.

Comment: Do you want to select page from pagination (eg show 2 page after loading)?

Comment: I want to set particular page number to display.

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand you, there are ```mfRowsOnPage``` for limiting items per page and ```mfActivePage``` for navigation https://github.com/mariuszfoltak/angular2-datatable#api